# Hi I want to make my chinese name

Tags: surnames

I am female.
My Birthday is may 25 2000.
I am short.
I am shy and have been told im scary quiet.
I have looked at flower names in chinese.
I would like any Form of chinese names old chinese simplified.
Im not sure if that was enough information.
Thank you.

Comment: You should ask your friends (who knows you better) to help to come up a name for you. If you have questions about the meaning of the name, then you can come back for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I have come across these sites that may be of interest:

- http://www.mandarintools.com/chinesename.html
- https://www.yourchineseastrology.com/chinese-name/generator.htm
- https://getrealchinesename.com/

I'm sure there are many others out there.

Good luck in finding your Chinese name.